# Throwing MySQL error if value passes a certain amount on update

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE table SET purchasedItems=
    [IF(purchasedItems + 1 > totalItems) THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Max value passed'
    END IF
        ELSE purchasedItems = purchasedItems + 1]
WHERE id=1;
```

This throws the error
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[IF(purchasedItems + 1 > totalItems) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAG' at line 1`

My table has purchasedItems initialized to 0, totalItems initialized to some value over 0, and a pk "id".

How can I throw an error if some new value + old value passes the total value in my table?

Thank you

Comment: Huh?   An `update` statement is not a trigger.  What you are trying to accomplish is not clear.

Comment: You're looking for a trigger or a check constraint, both of which can be used to validate such input. In the statement itself this is not possible.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to add more purchased items if the stock (totalItems - purchasedItems + 1) is greater or equal to zero 0

Comment: @GolezTrol is there not a way to add more purchasedItems if the condition (totalItems >= purchasedItems + 1) succeeds?

Comment: @GolezTrol I basically have to do a check to make sure this condition is true and then execute an update. Is there another way to do this atomically?